# Null space of quotient map

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. The quotient map $\pi$ is the linear map $\pi : V \rightarrow V/U$ defined by $\pi(v) = v + U$ for $\ v \in V$.

My linear algebra book claims that $\ker(\pi) = U$

I cant see why this is true.

Suppose $u \in U$, now $\pi(u) = u + U$, which I believe is not zero.

Comment: Can we know what's your book?

Comment: Linear algebra done right 3rd edition, page 97

Comment: when you say $null(\pi)$ you mean the kernel of $\pi$?

Comment: @KonKan, yes i do

Comment: I'd say $\;U\;$ is *not* only a subset of $\;V\;$ but rather a *subspace*, and $\;\pi\;$ is the canonical porjection $\;V\to V/U\;$.

Comment: typo! i meant subspace. thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I suppose the context is that $\pi:V \to V/U$ is the canonical projection. Then $$\ker\pi = \{v \in V \mid \pi(v) = 0_{V/U}\} = \{v \in V \mid v + U = U\} = U.$$

Note that the "zero vector" $0_{V/U}$ of $V/U$ is $U = 0 + U = \pi(0_V)$.

Comment: I was confused about the additive identity, thank you.

Comment: I think this answer deserves upvotes both because it is right and also because Alex succeeded in guessing the intention of the asker. +1

Comment: This was confusing to me as well; anyone else studying from Axler 3rd edition should refer to the bottom of page 52. The null space of $T : V \rightarrow W$ is the subspace that maps to the additive identity of $W$, which is not always the zero vector.

Comment: Also, it is noted in the two last lines on page 96.