# Why the null space of quotient map is $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am reading the textbook *Linear Algebra Done Right* Chapter 3 section E on Products and Quotients of Vectors Spaces.

It tried to prove the dimension of a quotient space is equal to $\text{dim }V/U = \text{dim }V -\text{dim }U$.

Before that it defines the quotient map $\pi$ as follow:

> Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. The quotient map $\pi$ is the linear map $\pi:V \to V/U$ defined by
>   $$\pi(v) = v+U$$
>   for $v \in V$.

I can understand that the range of $\pi$ is $v+U$ which is $V/U$ according to the definition of $V/U$.

**But I don't understand why the null space of $\pi$ is $U$. The book said it is due to the proof like this following:**

> Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $v,w \in V$. Then the following are equivalent:
>   $$v-w \in U$$
>   $$v+U=w+U$$
>   $$(v+U) \cap (w+U) \neq \emptyset$$

Comment: $v+U$ is rather the image of $v$ by $\pi$, instead of the range of $\pi$. If you take $u\in U$, then $\pi(u)=u+U$, but $u+U=\{u+v:\ v\in U\}=U$, since $U$ is a vector subspace. Therefore $\pi(u)=U=0+U$. Likewise if $\pi(v)=U$, then $v+U=U$, which implies that $v=v+0\in U$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of $\ker\pi$ is

\begin{align}
\ker \pi &= \{ x: \pi(x) = 0_{V/U} \}\\
&= \{x : x + U = 0_{V/U}\}\\
&= \{x :x + U = U \}\\
&= U
\end{align}

Comment: If I take $u \in U$, then $\pi(u) = u + U$. How can I see that $\pi(u) = 0$ from that?

Comment: @JOHN, $u \in U$. It is closed under addition. Hence $u + U = U.$

Comment: so $\pi(u) = U$. But I still cannot see how $\pi(u) = U$ becomes $\pi(u) = 0$

Comment: @JOHN $0_{V/U} = U$

Comment: After a month, I still a bit confused on why the zero vector of quotient space is U. 

the line $0_{V/U}=U$ seems like given which I don't understand

Comment: @JOHN, what do the elements of the quotient space $V/U$ look like? How is addition defined on this space?

Comment: After reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720672/null-space-of-quotient-map), I started to understand. The zero vector is not defined as the number 0, but the additive identity. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes because $(w + U) + (-w + U) = (0 + U) = U$

Comment: I assume $x+U\in U$ should be $x+U=U$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of thinking about it. Suppose that $\nu' \in$ $null\ \pi$. Then, we can see that:

$\pi(\nu') = \nu' + U = 0 + U$

*Because $0 + U$ is the additive identity of $V/U$.

And according to the additional proof that you provided, we see that $\nu'- 0 = \nu' \in U$.

So we see that whenever we map $\nu' \in U$ through $\pi$, we will always get $0 + U = U$ because the affine set of $\{\nu' + u : \nu',u \in U\} = \{0 + (\nu' + u)\}$. Since taking any vector from $U$ will map to the null space of $\pi$, we can see now that $null \ \pi = U$.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer but intuition to understand why $U_{0} (= U)$  should be the Nullspace:

The $0$ of any vector space is an element that gives you back what you added it to. In the case of a quotient space, $U$ is only such 'element' as:

\begin{align}
v + U + U_{0} = v + U
\end{align} as proved in Question 15 of Exercise 1.C

Note: Both $U$ and $U_{0}$ are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

@IAmNoOne has already given a good explanation. I want to add some details:

First, note that the additive identity of $V/U$ is $0+U$, which equals U. In other words, $0_{V/U} = U$.

Second, let $\pi(v) = 0_{V/U}$, solve $v$:

$$\because \pi(v) = v + U, v\in V$$

$$\therefore v+U=0_{V/U}=U$$
which can be written as:$$v+U = 0_V+U$$
From 3.85:
$$v-0_V=v\in U$$
$$\therefore \ker \pi\subset U$$
Apparently, $\forall u \in U, \pi(u) = 0_{V/U}$
$$\therefore U\subset \ker \pi$$
$$\therefore \ker \pi = U$$